# Object to string array java

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I am getting xml in a object back from a soap service.

```
<data><name>Test</name><name>Test</name><name>Test</name></data>
```

I need to convert that into an array so i can input it into a list

```
String[] accounts = result(this is my object);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listaccounts, accounts));
```

How can i do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse this XML using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947450/how-to-parse-this-xml-using-java)

Comment: You need to parse the XML. Googling will give you lots of sample codes.

Comment: Sorry thought there might be something like result.toarray(). I am a newbie to java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the XML structure is so simple then regular expression will solve it for you.

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<name>([^<]+)</name>");
.....
Matcher m = pattern.compile(xmlString);
List<String> retList = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m.find()) {
    retList.add(m.group(1));
}
return retList;
```

It could be parsed even faster with `String.indexOf();`

> Oh yeah: boatloads of people will tell you to use XML parser. It's complete overkill for simple XML. As long as it's not nested and you're not interested in attributes etc... simpler methods will do just fine.

Comment: Oh yeah: boatloads of people will tell you to use XML parser. It's complete overkill for simple XML. As long as it's not nested and you're not interested in attributes etc... simpler methods will do just fine.

Comment: But a real SOAP service response XML will not be as simple as posted..!

Comment: Well, he didn't say that, so that's an assumption. I've often dealt with soap calls which returned what's essentially a list of strings in simple xml. Hence why I said this method is for simple cases only.

Comment: The poster has clearly written `a object back from a soap service` so its not an assumption. BTW, the poster has accepted your answer, so it seems that he/she got what he/she was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for it xml parsers. Take a look at [this topic](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse the XML  response and then fill the String array. For XML parsing, you can use the SAXParser.

Hope this helps!